# WooCommerce subscriptions "invalid recurring shipping method"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

On my website, I use the plugin WooCommerce subscription, where I have a sign-up fee ($10 ish), and then a 7-day free trial. Then we charge the customer around $55 for the next product. I use a plugin called Smart Send, which is a logistic plugin for a Danish carrier.

When I order a product from my webshop, I get an error:

> "invalid recurring shipping method"

Even though everything looks to be set up perfectly in the system.

With the $55 order I can print out the label to my printer, but with the $10 sign-up fee I cannot because I get this notification.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I got the same error after trying to switch subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$recurring_shipping_package_key = WC_Subscriptions_Cart::get_recurring_shipping_package_key( $recurring_cart_key, $package_index );

if ( ! isset( $package['rates'][ $shipping_methods[ $recurring_shipping_package_key ] ] ) ) {

        if ( ! $added_invalid_notice ) {
                wc_add_notice( __( 'Invalid recurring shipping method.', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ), 'error' );
                $added_invalid_notice = true;
        }

        $shipping_methods[ $recurring_shipping_package_key ] = '';
}
```

Above is the section of the code from where this message is coming with WooCommerce Subscription.

```
woocommerce-subscriptions/includes/class-wc-subscriptions-cart.php Line 1168
```

This is error is coming because of some reason the shipping rate for the specific shipping method recurring_shipping_package_key is not set.